# Another way for "I was 12 dollars over what I had on me"

Tags: sentence-meaning

> I was 12 dollars over what I had on me.
>   <sub>Source: [24 Stories About the Kindness of Strangers | Reader's Digest](http://www.rd.com/true-stories/inspiring/kindness-strangers/)</sub>

I understand the meaning of the sentence, but I'd like to know how the sentence can be written in another way. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you perhaps mean "**It** was 12 dollars over what I had on me”?

Comment: Thanks, JMB. But it is "I" in the original sentence.

Comment: In a more general sense "I was a day late and a dollar short."

Answer (score 2):

> **It** was 12 dollars over what I had on me

**It** because the reference is not that ***you*** were 12 dollar over, but something (which is not named) that you wanted to buy

The phrase is better expressed as

> It was 12 dollars **more** than I had on me
>   I was 12 dollars **short**

both mean you didn't have enough money to buy something

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make any sense as it stands. I guess that in context it must mean that *I now owed twelve dollars more than the cash I had with me*, but that is only a guess. 
If you gave us some context, we might be able to say more.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Colin Fine. The sentence is from the kindness of strangers in February 2016,Reader's Digest. "When the supermarket cashier had added up my groceries, I was $ 12 over what I had on me."

Comment: OK, so it means "the total of my purchases came to $12 more than the cash I had with me".

Comment: And it is a typo - Should read _**It** was $12 over..._